# Python 3.6 Importing a class from a parallel folder

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have a file structure as shown below,

```
MainFolder
        __init__.py
        FirstFolder
                  __init__.py
                  firstFile.py
        SecondFolder
                  __init__.py
                  secondFile.py
```

Inside firstFile.py, I have a `class` named `Math` and I want to import this class in secondFile.py.

Code for firstFile.py

```
class Math(object):

    def __init__(self, first_value, second_value):

        self.first_value = first_value
        self.second_value = second_value

    def addition(self):

        self.total_add_value = self.first_value + self.second_value
        print(self.total_add_value)

    def subtraction(self):

        self.total_sub_value = self.first_value - self.second_value
        print(self.total_sub_value)
```

Code for secondFile.py

```
from FirstFolder.firstFile import Math

Math(10, 2).addition()
Math(10, 2).subtraction()
```

When I tried running secondFile.py I get this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'First'`

I am using Windows and the MainFolder is located in my C drive, under `C:\Users\Name\Documents\Python\MainFolder`

Possible solutions that I have tried are, creating the empty `__init__.py` for all main and sub folders, adding the dir of MainFolder into `path` under System Properties `environment variable` and using `import sys` & `sys.path.append('\Users\Name\Documents\Python\MainFolder')`.

Unfortunately, all these solutions that I have found are not working. If anyone can highlight my mistakes to me or suggest other solutions, that would be great. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are potentially two issues. The first is with your import statement. The import statement should be

```
from FirstFolder.firstFile import Math
```

The second is likely that your PYTHONPATH environment variable doesn't include your MainFolder.

On linux and unix based systems you can do this temporarily on the commandline with

export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/MainFolder

On windows

set PYTHONPATH="%path%;C:\path\to\MainFolder"

If you want to set it permanently, use setx instead of set

Comment: oh yea. apologies. the import statement was typo in the question on my part. I will try setting the PYTHONPATH. thank you.